# How can I add multiple numbers to some keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

```
mydict = {'5': 0, '2': 0, '1': 0, '12': 0}

number = input()

for i in range(0,4):
    if number == mydict[i]:
        mydict.keys[i]+=1

print(mydict)
```

I want input be like

- 5 --> {'5': 1, '2': 0, '1': 0, '12': 0} or
- 2 --> {'5': 0, '2': 1, '1': 0, '12': 0}

Comment: None of the values assigned to i are keys in mydict. If they were, the next line makes no sense anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are in hashmap group, so to find an item, there is no need for iteration over all the elements.

simply try:

```
mydict = {'5': 0, '2': 0, '1': 0, '12': 0}

inp = input()
mydict[inp] = mydict.get(inp, 0) + 1
```

It also allows you to enter numbers that are not currently in the dictionary with the initial value of 0 if it is the case you are looking for. Otherwise just get the key and increment it's value:

```
mydict[inp] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with simply not doing a loop:

```
mydict[number] += 1
```